# Convert long text string to proper HTML

Tags: javascript, html, string, vue.js

Say I have a long string from a wysiwyg text editor.

```
var string = '<div class="section"><h2 #id="section1">Find the thing</h2><p>Here is a paragraph.</p><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"><p>Here is a second paragraph</p><p>Woah, you mean to tell me there's three paragraphs!</p></div><div class="section"><h2 #id="section2">Find the thing</h2><p>Here is a paragraph.</p><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"><p>Here is a second paragraph</p><p>Woah, you mean to tell me there's three paragraphs!</p></div><div class="section"><h2 #id="section3">Find the thing</h2><p>Here is a paragraph.</p><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"><p>Here is a second paragraph</p><p>Woah, you mean to tell me there's three paragraphs!</p></div>'
```

Is there a Vue way to turn that string into structured HTML?

I want to create an array of the h2 elements from the original string and then pass the array to a child component as a prop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VueJS render property inside html string using v-html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59782289/vuejs-render-property-inside-html-string-using-v-html)

Comment: Not exactly. I want to pass an array of the h2 elements to a child component as a prop. I will clarify in my original post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something like that:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <child :h2Elements="h2Elements" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import child from './components/child.vue';

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: { child },
  data() {
    return {
      h2Elements: [],
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    let myRoot = document.createElement('div');
    myRoot.innerHTML = `<div class="section"><h2 #id="section1">Find the thing</h2><p>Here is a paragraph.</p><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"><p>Here is a second paragraph</p><p>Woah, you mean to tell me there's three paragraphs!</p></div><div class="section"><h2 #id="section2">Find the thing</h2><p>Here is a paragraph.</p><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"><p>Here is a second paragraph</p><p>Woah, you mean to tell me there's three paragraphs!</p></div><div class="section"><h2 #id="section3">Find the thing</h2><p>Here is a paragraph.</p><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"><p>Here is a second paragraph</p><p>Woah, you mean to tell me there's three paragraphs!</p></div>`;
    for (let div of myRoot.childNodes) {
      let [h2] = div.getElementsByTagName('h2');
      this.h2Elements.push(h2);
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

```
<template>
  <div>{{ h2Elements.map(h2 => h2.innerText) }}</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'child',
  props: ['h2Elements'],
};
</script>
```

Comment: That is what i was looking for. Thank you! Now if I can get my data to play nice.

Answer (score 0):

Try use the directie [v-html](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-html).

Attention: Note that the contents are inserted as plain HTML - they will not be compiled as Vue templates.

Comment: It would make your answer better if you took the OP's string and created a working example - just a suggestion

Comment: That's not exactly what I'm looking for. I want to create an array of the h2 elements from the original string and then pass the array to a child component as a prop. I will clarify in my original post. Thanks!